# Confusion with Remember username codes(javascript)?

Tags: java, javascript, session-cookies

I started learning javascript and i have a question with a webpage that i created. The webpage is a login page that shows some tableau reports when logged in. I need to create a remember me checkbox just like any other website like gmail or salesforce. I have copy pasted the codes below.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String app = context.getInitParameter("appName");
    String errorMessage = "";
    if ( session.getAttribute("error-message")!=null){
        errorMessage = (String) session.getAttribute("error-message");
    }
    %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

            <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

                    <title><%=app%> - Please login</title>

                    <link href="styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

                    <link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="styles/sidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
                    <style type='text/css' media='screen'>
                            body {
                              font-family: Tahoma;  
                              font-size: 12px !important;
                              padding-top: 40px;
                              padding-bottom: 40px;
                              background-color: #fff;
                            }
                            .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
                            .form-signin .checkbox {
                              margin-bottom: 10px;
                            }

                            .navbar{
                                border-color: #ccc;
                            }
                            .alert-warning{
                                margin-top: 15px;
                            }
                            .validation-summary-errors{
                                font-family: Tahoma !important;
                                font-size: 12px !important;
                                color: #b94a48;
                                margin-top: 35px;
                                margin-bottom: -15px;
                            }
                            .col-md-8{
                                padding-left: 5px;
                            }
    /*                        .navbar-inverse{
                              border-color: #ccc;
                              background: #ddf0f8;  Old browsers 
                              background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ddf0f8 0%, #ffffff 63%);  FF3.6+ 
                              background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ddf0f8), color-stop(63%,#ffffff));  Chrome,Safari4+ 
                              background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ddf0f8 0%,#ffffff 63%);  Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ 
                              background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ddf0f8 0%,#ffffff 63%);  Opera 11.10+ 
                              background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ddf0f8 0%,#ffffff 63%);  IE10+ 
                              background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ddf0f8 0%,#ffffff 63%);  W3C 
                              filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ddf0f8', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );  IE6-9 
                            }*/
                    </style>

        </head>

            <body>
            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img class="logo" src="img/Nexius_logo.png"/>

            </div>


        </div>



                            <div class='inner col-md-8'>

                                    <%=errorMessage%>
                                    <form action='LoginServlet' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='form-horizontal' role='form' autocomplete='off'>
                                            <h4 class="form-signin-heading">&nbsp;</h4> 

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for='username' class='col-md-2 control-label'>User name</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type='text' class="form-control"  name='user' id='username'  />
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for='password' class='col-md-2 control-label'>Password</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type='password' class="form-control" name='pwd' id='password' />
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Login</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"><div style="position: absolute; top: -45px; left: 100px; width: 240px;">


                                                        <input onClick="checkCookie()" type="checkbox" value="Remember me">Remember username<br>


                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </form>
                            </div>


            <script type='text/javascript'>

            function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
    {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname)
    {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
      {
      var c = ca[i].trim();
      if (c.indexOf(name)===0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
      }
    return "";
    }

    function checkCookie()
    {
    var user=getCookie("user");

    if (user!=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("username").value = user;
      }
    else 
      {

        if (user!=="" && user!=null)
        {
        setCookie("user",user,30);
        }
      }
    }


            </script>





            </body>
    </html>
```

Mostly the upper part is just CSS. In the below part i have writtten the codes to get the username on the text box and pass it to the setcookie function below. So i need it like an usual page like when remember username check box was checked, the username should show up when the page is opened, but for me what it does is, when i open the webpage only when i click on the "remember username" checkbox the username pops up in the username textbox. Now sure what to do about this? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for cookies only when user clicks on the `remember me` button. You need to check for cookie on document load, for instance.

Add `onload` handler on body tag this way: `<body onload=checkCookie()>`. You need to also remove `onClick="checkCookie()"` from your remember me button.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much, it works fine, but even if i do not click on the remember me check box the browser seem to remember my username, seems like my the function() and the checkbox are not connected atll, is there a solution for that?

Comment: also in the lower part i have written codes to get the username, my manager asked me to make it remember password also, hence i replicated the same codes changing the method names only and replacing the username text box to password text box in this part,
if (user!=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("password").value = user;
      }

I added this function in the <body onload="checkCookie();checkCookie1();"> the second function being for password. would this work? am i doing something wrong? or what is the best way to do this? 
Thank you for the help!